# Firebase Retrieves Item multiple times (Everything is doubled)

Tags: angularjs, mobile, web, firebase, ionic-framework

So I call the function that fetches data from Firebase and push that data in an Array of objects. However, for some reason I have two of everything, everything is doubled as if the retrieve function gets called twice!

Here is how it looks:

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrZLR.png)

Code:

```
cApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $rootScope) { 

$scope.allMeals = [];


    // getting meals from database
    $scope.getMeals = function () { 
    $scope.allMeals = [];

        var mealsRef = new Firebase("https://<my app id here>.firebaseio.com/Meals"); 

    mealsRef.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
    var newPost = snapshot.val();
    console.log("Name: " + newPost.name);
    console.log("Price: " + newPost.price);

      $scope.allMeals.push({
        name: newPost.name, 
        price: newPost.price
      })
  });

 };


// calling get meals function
$scope.getMeals();
```

This is starting to give me headache!

Comment: I've seen this happen when you've defined your app or controller in more than one location.  Check to make sure you are not defining "ng-controller='HomeCtrl'" in more than one location in your html - or if you're using a routeProvider ensure your not defining the controller in multiple locations.

Comment: @Kyle  Thanks man. The function was being executed even if I did not call it (I don't know why), so when I call the function that becomes the second time it runs.

Comment: Interesting, so if you remove $scope.getMeals() from your controller it still runs the function?

Comment: @Kyle Yes, that sounds not what you expect, but surprisingly, yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function was being executed even if I did not call it (I don't know why), so when I call the function that becomes the second time it runs.